# How to Use ejabberd register module for custom login

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, ejabberd-module, ejabberd-api, ejabberd-hooks

I am new to ejabberd and erlang and have created a basic application that first checks that whether the user has login or not. So basically it checks the mnesia table of login and confirms this.

Now I saw that ejabberd also has a registration process for users as in`ejabberdctl register username host password` and I since I was using sql authentication I saw that there is a table named `users` which has all the users and the password stored.

I wanted to know the flow of sequence that how these values get stored there and was hoping to use it to push these values of `username and password` into my mnesia table for login.

I had a look at ejabberd developer guide and found that mod_register handles the registration of a new user but I could not trace down exactly what function is getting used inside it to do all the proceedings.

I was using the method of writing info messages to the logs. 
Can anybody help me on this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: To be more specific I checked that whenever I register a new user from command line then I am not able to track the presence of mod_register but if I am using a client(Pidgin) then I can see mod_register being called.Anyone having any Idea about why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

`ejabberd_auth` module is reponsible for user registration mod_register call  `ejabberd_auth:try_register/3` function and `ejabberd_auth:try_register/3` call these modules (`ejabberd_auth_sql`, `ejabberd_auth_riak`, `ejabberd_auth_mnesia`, `ejabberd_auth_external`, `ejabberd_auth_anonymous` and `ejabberd_auth_pam`). These modules also have function `try_register/3`.The module `ejabberd_auth`  calls these module according to setting of ejabberd configuration file auth methods (internal, external, odbc etc.).

So study these modules and function to understand flow of ejabberd registration.

[image: Sample flow]

Comment: Thank you for the reply,it was helpful.